# mootools FX.slideOut collapses table row

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-fx

I'm borrowing some code from a [David Walsh tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/animated-ajax-record-deletion-mootools) on animated delete with mootools.

When I use the Mootools FX.slide on a table row, it sort of collapses the row horizontally before sliding it up, which is not the desired effect.

There's a fiddle here if you'd like to take a look-- http://jsfiddle.net/gNvvT/

How can I make this effect a smooth slide vertically, rather than collapsing left, then up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid `Fx.Slide` can't work with table rows, but only with block elements.
As Dimitar Christoff said to you.

I've modified your fiddle to get around this problem. From the code you posted, it seems you are quite practical with Mootools, so I just wrote some comments on the code. I'm sure you will get the trick.

> **http://jsfiddle.net/gNvvT/5/**

Let me know if it works on your *real world* application!

**Edit.** There was some useless code I left from previous tests. I removed it and I updated the fiddle URL.

Comment: fair enough, +1 for effort :) seeing tables makes me cringe these days, even for tabular data. http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com/

Comment: I agree. There's always the way to do tables using block elements... However there are cases where, in fact, tables are quite comfortable...

Comment: @DimitarChristoff-- thanks for your help! I wish I could accept both answers. I appreciate you guys taking the time to show alternatives and examples. I agree that I will probably end up rebuilding this form in divs, but at the moment I don't want to make that major change, so I am using lorenzo's workaround. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

this is because `TR` are not real block style elements, it's `display: table-row` (iirc).

The `Fx.Slide` class actually has just 2 tricks it tries to employ to make it appear like it's dissolving, basically:

1. set overflow from visible to hidden, which - in the context of a TR, makes no sense.
2. (optional) it can wrap an element in a wrapper and then collapse that, but once again, the wrapper becomes the direct parent of the element and it's a div, which you cannot do in a table.

it then allows it to manipulate the height of the element and make it smaller etc.

the jump happens as it changes the display/overflow and it all goes funny after as it collapses the table.

you should consider an alternative way, like fade and when available, scale transform.

Comment: it does not need to be tricky, depends what you are after. this is with a simple css enhancement and scale: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/gNvvT/6/ - you can have a fallback via just '.fade()' if not supported

Comment: I tried to make something that behave exactly as julio intended. It do not use CSS3 transitions. However, interesting use of `destroy.delay()`, never thought that is so easy an clearer that `.delay(function() { this.destroy(); }.bind())` XD

Comment: its only good to use as a pattern when you have a saved reference to the element so you can bind it to the delayed method.